# Sum preceding rows once condition met in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a solution to summing the total number of rows once a specific condition is met in a particular column.

Simplified sample data:

```
  rbind( c('Group A', "eventcode.1", "10:00"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.3", "09:59"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.4", "09:57"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.6", "09:56"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.4", "09:52"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.4", "09:51"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.9", "09:48"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.1", "09:46"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.3", "09:45"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.4", "09:41"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.8", "09:40"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.4", "09:37"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.1", "09:33"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.2", "09:31"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.3", "09:30"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.5", "09:28"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.6", "09:28"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.7", "09:27"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.2", "09:26"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.9", "09:26"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.11", "09:24"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.7", "09:20"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.1", "09:17"),
                 c('Group A', "eventcode.2", "09:15"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.4", "09:12"),
                 c('Group B', "eventcode.4", "09:08")) %>%
  as.data.frame() -> temp.data 

colnames(temp.data) = c('Group', 'Event', "Time")
```

This is a reduced set of data (original will have 40+ columns of data related to the events), but the important thing is to know that there will only be two types of groups in each dataset and that these groups register action events that have a specific code assigned to it. Whenever a specific event code is triggered, I want to identify that row and create a new variable that sums the amount of rows that lead up to the event (grouped by each group A/B), so long as there is no break between group's and the actions being taken. The event code that triggers it is "eventcode.1". Then, in those previous rows I want to sum the occurence of a particular eventcode (eventcode.4) and the total time of events leading up to the eventcode.1 by the Group that is completing logged events.

I.e.,

```
row 1 - Group A - would have a value of 0, eventcode.4 count of 0, and time count of 0 seconds
row 8 - Group A - would have a value of 2, eventcode.4 count of 1, and time count of 5 seconds
row 13 - Group B - would have a value of 3, eventcode.4 count of 2, and time count of 8 seconds
row 23 - Group A - would have a value of 1, , eventcode.4 count of 0, and time count of 3 seconds
```

Comment: How is `value` and `timecount` calculated ?

Comment: @RonakShah it is the sum of eventcode.4 occurences that take place over the preceding total rows, and the total time difference in seconds (time is a countdown, so technically whenever eventcode.1 is registered, it is the minimum time, and the maximum time is the first event recorded by either group A/B - so in the output for row 8, it is the time difference between row 8 and row 6, which is 9:51 to 9:46 or 5 seconds.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach (using `dplyr`, and `lubridate` for the time conversion):

```
temp.data %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   mutate(brk1 = lag(V2, 1) == 'eventcode.1',
          brk2 = lag(V1, 1) != V1
         ) %>%
   mutate(grp = cumsum(
                   (1L * coalesce(brk1, F)) + 
                   (1L * coalesce(brk2, F)))
          ) %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%
   filter(last(V2) == 'eventcode.1') %>%
   summarize(
      row = last(rn),
      group = first(V1),
      value = n() - 1,
      cnt = sum(if_else(V2 == 'eventcode.4', 1, 0)),
      tmct = seconds(ms(first(V3))) - seconds(ms(last(V3)))
   ) %>%
   select(-grp);
```

Which produces:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
    row group   value   cnt tmct    
  <int> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <Period>
1     1 Group A     0     0 0S      
2     8 Group A     2     1 5S      
3    13 Group B     3     2 8S      
4    23 Group A     1     0 3S
```